# How to retrieve an OPC item with OPCFoundation.NetStandard.Opc.Ua

Tags: c#, opc-ua

I try to use the NuGet package *OPCFoundation.NetStandard.Opc.Ua* for retrieving data from an opc-server. But I can't figrure out how to directly address an individual item by name ("Channel1.Device1.Tag1") in order to read it or make a subscription.

I have downloaded and studied the complete sample code from OPCFoundation's GitHub repository, but I only found code that retrieves all available items (by browsing the server) and then let the user pick one of those.

I need to somehow lookup an item directly from its name ("Channel1.Device1.Tag1") in order to obtain a *NodeId*-instance, which I can then use for reading or subscribing  (I know how to do that part once I have the *NodeId*).

If anyone could just post a short example or point me to some sample code that does the job, I would be very happy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've established the session, one option would be to look for the *_System* object within the *Objects* folder in order to get the *namespace index* since [it seems can change](http://documentation.unified-automation.com/uasdkhp/1.0.0/html/_l2_ua_node_ids.html).

```
ReferenceDescriptionCollection refdescs;

      byte[] continuationPoint;


      session.Browse(null, null, ObjectIds.ObjectsFolder, 0u, BrowseDirection.Forward, ReferenceTypeIds.HierarchicalReferences, true, (uint)NodeClass.Variable | (uint)NodeClass.Object | (uint)NodeClass.Method, out continuationPoint, out refdescs);


      foreach (var item in refdescs)
      {
        if (item.DisplayName.Text == "_System")
        {
          var nsi = item.NodeId.NamespaceIndex.ToString();
          Console.WriteLine($"Namespace Index {nsi}");
        }
      }
```

Once you get it, your identifier for reading/writing would be in the following format

```
ns=[NamespaceIndex];s=Channel1.Device1.Tag1
```